# Get and print the Date Component of a DateTime Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

I am building my asp.net C# website. It uses a Database, which also contains a Date/Time value, which I get and parse to DateTime object. When I try to only print, directly, the date component, it also prints the time component. I tried DateTime.date but never worked.
Here are my relevant code sections:

.ASPX file:

```
<div class="BottomRight">
    <h2>Uploaded <%=UploadDate.Date.ToString()%></h2>
</div>
```

.cs file:

```
UploadDate = DateTime.Parse(row["UploadDate"].ToString());
```

note: `UploadDate` - public string. there is nothing wrong in the data set and data row values, just get only the date printed.
Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, why do you have to parse anything? Why isn't it stored as binary date/time data in the database? What database is it? Does it not have a dedicated type for date/time data? If it is binary date/time data, why are you converting that to a `String` and then back to a `DateTime` again?

Comment: @jmcilhinney I am using OleDb database, and my value formatted as Date/Time value. I don't really know how to do that, but any solution may be helpful... thanks

Comment: "I am using OleDb database". No you're not. There's no such thing. OLE DB providers are a layer that sits on top of databases and other data sources to provide a consistent API for applications. If you're talking about a `Date/Time` data type then perhaps you're using an Access database, i.e. an MDB or ACCDB file. In that case, your value is already a `DateTime` so converting it to a `String` and then back to a `DateTime` is pointless and silly. Just cast it as that type, i.e. `UploadDate = (DateTime) row["UploadDate"]`. As has been said, you then specify the format when you call `ToString`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify the format. See [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) on MSDN.

For example:

```
<div class="BottomRight">
  <h2>Uploaded <%=UploadDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")%></h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the code snippets you posted are wrong.  This:

```
UploadDate = DateTime.Parse(row["UploadDate"].ToString());
```

should be this:

```
UploadDate = (DateTime) row["UploadDate"];
```

and then this:

```
UploadDate.Date.ToString()
```

should be this:

```
UploadDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

or whatever format is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try that.

Answer (score 0):

do the following in your .cs file (back-end) code

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(row["UploadDate"].ToString());       
string NewDate = date.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Output of `NewDate` would be like this `19/08/2018` and then just read the value in HTML file as string value.